# can't send an Email by liferay 6.2

Tags: java, liferay-6

I am facing an issue.

> com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine.send(InternetAddress from,
>   InternetAddress to, String subject,String body, boolean htmlFormat)

or

> InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com");
>         fromAddress.setPersonal(personal);
>
> ```
>   InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress("xzy@gmail.com");       
>   InternetAddress[] ccAddresses = null; 
>
>   MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
>   mailMessage.setTo(toAddress);
>
>   mailMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);  
>   mailMessage.setSubject(subject);                
>   mailMessage.setBody(emailBody);     
>   mailMessage.setHTMLFormat(true);
>
>   MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(mailMessage);
> ```

Tried above both code with different "from Email address" than one configured in mail configuration. But it is still sending email from the address configured in control panel.its not sending the email through above mention "abc@gmail.com"

Can anyone make this clear how is this possible to send email from different email address rather than mention in control panel Configuration ,as we not giving any password to above code.

Comment: Not everyone might understand liferay. Please add a code snippet to help others understand your problem.

Comment: you want that whatever email address you pass to it, it should send email using that adress ? am i right ?

Comment: yes, is it possible to  send email through what i mention in from address (fromAddress = new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"); ) ? and whats the way to provide the password of  'from address'

Comment: I know it's a long shot but years ago when I had to work with liferay I may had the same issue and I resolved it going into the email control panel  form and resubmit it. After it was resubmit I was able to send emails. (see https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14787465/exclusive?controlPanelCategory=portlet_19)